# React Router Switch: change rendered component from within the matched Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router's Switch for my app's navigation, which looks something like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={/product/:id} component={ProductPage} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>
```

The last Route handles any urls that are not matched (404's). Note that when this happens, the URL doesn't change, which is the desired behavior.

When the first route is matched, the ProductPage component fetches data from the server for the supplied id. However, when the id does not exist in the database, the server returns a 404. In this case I would like to render the NotFoundPage component, without the url changing. In other words, when a user enters /product/999 and this product doesn't exist, the NotFoundPage component should be rendered without the URL changing to something like /404.

I know I could use history.push() to programmatically navigate to another page, but this will change the url.

So to sum it up, is it possible to change the component that is rendered by Switch from inside the component rendered by a matched Route?

Thank you so much!

EDIT:
I am aware that I can just conditionally render the NotFoundPage. However, I'd like to avoid having to set this up for each page individually. Instead, I'd like to add this logic to my function that makes the request.

Comment: Did you try this: `<Route path='*' exact={true} component={errorcomponent} />` from a existing stack overflow question

Comment: @GayatriDipali That is equivalent to the second Route in my code snippet.